# How do I trigger a window resize event, when using cy.viewport()

Tags: cypress

My objective is to develop an e2e test in Cypress for an Angular SPA application, testing if elements are hidden/shown as expected in different viewports.

I have tried using the Cypress [viewport](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport.html) command, but this does not seem to trigger the [window resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

Is this event something I have to dispatch manually? Thanks in regards.

**update**

The problem was not related to Cypress and resize, but rather change detection in Angular. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cypress-resize), if other people need to test this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce. For me, the `resize` event is properly triggered on `window`:

(tested on `3.3.1`, `3.5.0`, both headless & headed)

```js
describe('test', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        let resizeEventFired = false;
        cy.window().then(win => {
            win.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                resizeEventFired = true;
            });
        });

        cy.viewport(123, 456);
        cy.wrap().should(() => {
            expect(resizeEventFired).to.eq(true);
        });
    });
});
```

If it still doesn't work for you, or you subscribe on some non-standard event or element, then you can do this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('viewport', (origFn, ...args) => {
    return origFn(...args).then(() => {
        const window = cy.state('window');
        window.dispatchEvent(new window.UIEvent('resize'));
    });
});
```

(I'm triggering `resize`-compatible event on `window`, but you can do whatever you want).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test this today. I am thinking that my problems could maybe be related to Angular not doing change detection, but I will test it and find out.

Comment: You are correct. I have created a stackblitz, for other people to play with.